# An imagining picture match 'on the fly' literal

Tags: vocabulary

I am reading a sentence

> It’s also handy if you’re constructing objects **on the fly** and want to interact with them without assigning them a name first.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_fly) defines
On the fly is a phrase used to describe something that is being changed while the process that the change affects is ongoing.

There's an good explanition in
[English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144361/what-is-meaning-of-on-the-fly-in-computer-science/144364#144364) The general gist in a program is that it is an activity that is done when needed, rather than being done in a separate execution (typically beforehand).

I barely discern its meaning whereas cannot imagine an a picture of it literally.
I tried my best to understand it by imagination.

'on the fly', so 'the fly' is a flying vehicle, something needed on it.

or juggling game, 'on the fly' specifies the balls flying in the air without hitting your hand.

[image]

The two scenes helps a little bit to match its actual meaning.

What kind of image or imagination best match 'on the fly' literally?

Comment: Even as a native speaker, it's not particularly obvious where "on the fly" came from, so I personally don't have an image in my head when I think of it. Apparently, it came from [baseball](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/353390/191178), so maybe that will help you if you really need an image.

Comment: There are a couple of expressions in English that are conceptually very similar to the idiom ***on the fly***: ***on the go*** and ***on the move***. I personally as a nonnative speaker when hear ***on the fly*** imagine doing something while literally flying somewhere. To me, it's a process being done within another process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [the Wiktionary definition of "on the fly"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_the_fly) is pretty accurate:

> done as one goes, or during another activity.

This is an example of repairing a locomotive:

[image: group of men working on a stationary locomotive]

This is an example of repairing a locomotive "on the fly":

[image: Picture of a man on a moving train from the movie Unstoppable]

Describing an activity as "on the fly" can also mean that it's spontaneous. For example, if you just do whatever exercises pop into your head as you're exercising instead of doing a routine that you decided on beforehand, you are "making up your workout on the fly".